# Partially reference a DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I have a library DLL full with sort algorithmn, parsers, validators, converters etc. The DLL is about 40 Mb (that is not much I know but still). Now I would like to reference just the parsers of that DLL. The point is to get out those parsers without shipping 40 Mb to the customer.

Is there a way everytime I make a release build to just take those up-to-date parsers from my library, store them into some kind of `.partialDll` file and deliver only them to the customer? The result would be me keeping all my helper classes in one big library which keeps growing and the customers get just what they ordered..

I guess I would need to deal with alot of reflection to achieve something like this, right? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code for your dll? If so you might be able to achieve this with preprocessors to make the dll smaller depending on the build type you choose. Or, if you can pull code into separate projects and use multiple dll's.

Comment: Have you looked at multifile assemblies? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/168k2ah5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know in my question I keep saying my library but the truth is that I do not have full acess of the source code.

Comment: Than the only way I can see is to use dissembler to generate source code for every single class in you assembly, grab only the sources into which you're interested in & recompile. In practical life I don't think it is worth it though.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start with a quote [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3677y81(v=vs.110).aspx):

> *"Assemblies are the building blocks of .NET Framework applications; they form the fundamental unit of deployment […]."*

Note that the quote is about assemblies, not about DLLs. There's a difference!

Although most .NET assemblies consist of exactly one DLL file, that is not a strict requirement: An assembly can in fact consist of more than one file; such a ["multi-file assembly"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe(VS.80).aspx) can, for instance, consist of several DLLs, which in turn are called "netmodules". (A netmodule might have a `.netmodule` file extension by convention, but it's really a DLL containing .NET metadata and bytecode.) Each multi-file assembly has exactly one "main" module which carries the metadata that references all the other assembly files and so ties them together into a logical whole.

While an assembly has to be deployed in full (as per the above quote), the .NET runtime can load only those netmodules that are actually required for JIT code compilation and execution.

So you can split up an assembly into several parts, and have the runtime load only what is actually needed; but you cannot do the same to a netmodule / DLL file. **A DLL file can only be deployed and loaded in its entirety.**

Note also that Visual Studio's support for netmodules is non-existent for all practical purposes, so most people don't use them, which is why you see so few multi-file assemblies in the real world.

The bottom line is this: In practice, **if you or your clients are interested in only a part of an assembly ("DLL"), then it's usually easier to split a large assembly (that is, one large Visual Studio project) into several inter-dependent assemblies (several smaller Visual Studio projects).**

Comment: If you need half a brick, you cut your brick in two.

Comment: … or, like in this case, instead of manufacturing bricks that are too large, you produce smaller ones of the right size.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, there is no way to achieve that. Once you pack "everything" into a module and compile it, you can't split that module later into smaller ones. (well, ok, you can analyze the bytecode and rewrite the assembly, see the end of this post).

For me, your nullhypothesis seems wrong. You don't need to work with "one huge library that keeps all your helper classes", and really, you dont want, or you will not want to either. If you don't feel like that, I assure you that in time, years maybe, you will hate such one-to-have-it-all approach.

This is exactly what you want to escape from and this is why .Net and many other languages/environments support concept of "libraries" or "modules" and allow you to use multiple of them, and that's why most of the projects you see everywhere aren't created as "one huge EXE". It's much easier to reuse, analyze and even hunt bugs when you have it in smaller chunks.

--

However, if you'd insist, there are ways (ugly) to achive something-like you think. I assume that the "huge DLL" is in C# and is controlled by you.

First, somewhat naiive but working way, is to use "file links". In VisualStudio you can have a project that contains tons of files and producess a BigDLL "all.dll", and just by its side you can create another project that will **not contain** any files at all, but that will contain **links to the first projects' files**. Use typical "Add a file.." option to a project and note that near the final "Add" button there's a down arrow that expands to "Add as link..".

This will cause the file to stay in HugeProject, but the SmallProject will see the file too and when SmallProject is compiled, it will pull the code from that file too.

Note that this way you will actually build **two separate modules assemblies**: big one and small one, and your final product will need to reference the small one.

This way is naiive and ugly, it is just as if you manually copied/splitted the huge project into smaller ones, but with the tiny advantage is that you don't need to copy the code files around.

--

intermission for side-thoughts:

- you can use `#if` to conditionally turn off some currently-unused code, however setting the flags that drive those IFs will be cumbersome
- you can edit .csproj files and use MSBuild conditional clauses to automatically exclude unused code files from your HugeProject during final builds, however setting the flags that drive those IFs will be cumbersome too

--

The second way is to keep everything in the HugeProject, and to have your application(s) reference it directly, and then after building and testing everything, just before packing that and sending to customer - use some kind of trimming utility that will check what parts of code are referenced and that will remove all dead code from the assemblies. I can't give you any name for such utility, but many **obfuscators** come with such feature.

They will run through your *compiled* code, cross-reference everything, change/remove/trash class/method/propertynames and also they may as a bonus remove unused bits. Then, they'll write mangled assemblies back to disk ensuring that they reference each other and not the original ones from before mangling.

example: [See a question related to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850672/is-it-possible-to-remove-unused-code-assemblies-in-net)
example: [See an example of such utility](https://github.com/glueckkanja/ILStrip) also consider ILMerge for better results.

Cons - utility may leave some trash it couldn't decide whether it is used or not, finding/testing/buying it may take some time and resources, you can have some signing problems since the stripped-assembly will be a brand new assembly, etc. Also, such utilities have problems if you invoke some code only by reflection and it may require you to provide some extra hints or to make sure the code "seems to be used" (example: a whole namespace of "plugins" that implement "IPlugin" and then your app searched that NS for Types and uses Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate them; no hard-linked usages, trimmer may decide to remove all plugins as "unused"; you'll need to configure trimmer carefully or be suprised).

Probably a few other ways could be found too, but seriously, in most of the times, you don't want to waste your time on that, especially manually. So just tidy up your code and split it into small libs, or start looking for automatic obfuscator&trimmer.