# Remove unused functions from c# source code

Tags: c#, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible to remove unused functions from c# source code? For example, in this code:

```
  internal class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args){

    #if !INIT 
      Console.WriteLine("init");
    #elif DETAILS
      Console.WriteLine("details");
      DontAddMePleaseFunction();
    #endif    
    #if FINAL
      Console.WriteLine("final");
    #endif
    }

    public static void DontAddMePleaseFunction(){
      Console.WriteLine("lalala");
    }
  }
```

`DontAddMePleaseFunction` is never called, but still added to the source code. Now, I can wrap it in `#IF INIT #ENDIF` (given that INIT is defined) and it will be removed, but I wonder if there is an automatic way of omitting unused functions from c# source code?

Comment: This is complicated via the support for reflection. For example, the method may be called as part of a plugin, so it's not called directly by your code but may be via someone elses.

Comment: I have multiple version of a project. Customer A agreed on version A, customer B on B. A shoud not see the source code for B and vice versa. I am not worried about performance, but literally about removing what shouldn't be seen.

Comment: Perhaps you want conditional compilation.

Comment: conditional compilation.. thats using #if and similar statements, right?  While I agree, there is a lot to be conditionally compiled.

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to make your application modular and include the relevant module for each customer?

Comment: Will try. Unforunately this came as an afterthough, so better get busy.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850672/is-it-possible-to-remove-unused-code-assemblies-in-net) are few suggestions like [ILStrip](https://github.com/glueckkanja/ILStrip) or [SmartAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/).  Or you can try to look at [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) may be something could be done with it.

Comment: What do you need this for? Such a method adds a few hundred bytes to the size of your assembly, that's all.